# What does the number at the end of each stacktrace line mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, stack-trace

I am examining some Xcode crash logs, and I was wondering the the number at the end of each line means:

```
0 Powercents 0x000781de testflight_backtrace + 142
1 Powercents 0x00078d6c TFSignalHandler + 212
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x319937ec _sigtramp + 48
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3198920e pthread_kill + 54
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3198229e abort + 94
5 AppSupport 0x35f70c2e abortAfterPassingIntegrityCheck + 38
6 AppSupport 0x35f70ee6 runIntegrityCheckAndAbort + 526
7 AppSupport 0x35f7102c checkResultWithStatement + 120
8 AppSupport 0x35f72a12 _connectAndCheckVersion + 1058
9 AppSupport 0x35f72ab6 CPSqliteDatabaseConnectionForWriting + 42
10 AppSupport 0x35f72b8c CPSqliteDatabaseRegisterFunction + 20
11 AddressBook 0x345523f6 ABCDBContextCreateWithPathAndAddressBook + 214
12 AddressBook 0x34546428 ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigrationInProcessLinkingAndResetSortKeys + 232
13 AddressBook 0x34554cd6 ABAddressBookCreate + 14
14 TextInput 0x377981c4 _ZN2KB45fill_with_matchable_strings_from_address_bookERNS_7HashmapINS_6StringEbEE + 16
15 TextInput 0x3779edf4 _ZN2KB21DynamicDictionaryImpl28background_load_address_bookERKNS_16StaticDictionaryE + 200
16 TextInput 0x3779f72e _ZN2KBL14BackgroundLoadEPv + 278
17 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a734 _pthread_start + 320
18 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3194a5ef thread_start + 7
```

Comment: Educated guess - offset (bytes) inside the function body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crash log is not symbolicated. If you symbolicate it, it should give you info that's easier to interpret.

Here's a document that talks about that:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Answer (score 3):

they are machine code offset

for example in this picture,

- `libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg`'s machine code start from address `0x18474f054`.
- `libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg + 68`,as you can see ,this is where `mach_msg_trap`was called, and `mach_msg_trap`'s addrss is `0x18474f21c`,
- `libsystem_kernel.dylib mach_msg + 72` is where a breakpoint will stop,which is equal to `0x18474f054 + 0x72`

[image]